How can I report on the first activity date or first contribution date for a constituent?
I'm looking for a way to report on the first activity date OR first contribution date for a contact. For the activity date I'd like to download this data and then for the contributions add them to a group. Does anyone have any advice on if I can pull a report, or use the SearchKit to find this data?

Fortunately, every contribution generates an activity, so you can achieve your goal with just an activity search.
In SearchKit:

Search for contacts
With Activities (required)
Group by: Contact ID
For every activity column you add, use the "Group First" aggregate function, order by date.


Amazing thankyou @coleman. I've seen with the actions I can download them but doesn't look like I have the ability to add them to a group? Do you know why?
